# Let $G= \{a, b, c, d\}$ be a group. Complete the followig Cayley table for this group.

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

Let $G= \{a, b, c, d\}$ be a group. Complete the followig Cayley table for this group.[image]

My solution goes like this:

> 1. From the Cayley table, $d^2=d.d=d\implies d.d=d.e $ , since $G$ is a group and an identity element $e$ must be in $G$. Thus, $d.d=d.e\implies d=e$. Hence, $d $ is the identity element . Thus, the first row, is $\{d,a,b,c\}$.
> 2. Now, , for the next row the 1st entry i.e $a.d=a$, then we have, $a^2=c,a.b=d$ and $a.c$ cant be $a$ as $c$ is not the identity element,  neither can it be $c$ as $a$ is not the idenity element . So , $a.c $ can be either $b$ or $d$. But $a.c$ cant be $d$ as $d=e$ and given $a.b=d=e$ and since $G$ is a group , so, $a.c=b$. Also, $b.a=d=e$. So, the second row is $\{a,c,d,b\}$
> 3. Now, we go for the 3rd row, here we have $b.d=b$, then $b.a=d$, next $b^2$ cant be $b$ or $d$, so $b^2$ can be either $a$ or $c$. But if, $b^2=a$, then $b^3=d=e$ and hence $o(b)=3$. But then by Lagrange's theorem this is not possible.  So, $b^2=c$. Then, $b.c$ cant be $b,c$ or $d$. Thus $b.c=a$. So the 3rd row becomes $\{b,d,c,a\}$.
> 4. Finally, we have the 4th row, we have $c.d=c$, then we have $c.a$ cant be $a$ or $c$ or $d$ , hence $c.a=b$ , next, $c.b$ cant be $c,b$ or $d$ . So, $c.b=a$, and now , $c^2=d$. So, the 4th row becomes $\{c,b,a,d\}$.
> 5. Thus, the rows are $\{d,a,b,c\}$,$\{a,c,d,b\}$,$\{b,d,c,a\}$,$\{c,b,a,d\}$ respectively in the above table.

Is the above solution valid? Is the proof correct? Is it valid? If not, then where is the problem occuring?...

Comment: it's hard to read without a paragraph :) ; advice: let $G$ be a group; then $\forall g\in G, g^{-1}g=gg^{-1}=e$; you could have specified this before writing $d.d=d.e\implies d=e$  or say something " in a group, we can simplify on the left."

Comment: Which book is this from?

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is correct, but the process is a bit complicated. Once you figure out that $d$ is the identity, it is enough to use the fact that no row or column of a Cayley table contains repeating elements (for $ab = ac$ iff $b = c$ iff $ba = ca$).

Also note that there are only two groups of order $4$ up to isomorphism: $\mathbb{Z}/ 4\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. In $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, the inverse of every element is itself, so we can exclude that possibility immediately.

Comment: We can be more precise : $\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Indeed - and the inverse of every element in $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is itself, so we can exclude that possibility immediately.

Comment: For me and for OP, I should be more precise : $(\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z,+) (\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z,+)$ up to isomorphism.